# cocos2dx sometimes ignore setposition()

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, cocos2d-x

I have a cycle to put objects in the screen. but for some reason some objects although printed the right coordinates in the printf are at the point (0,0) as if he had not done set it position.

```
for (int i =0 ; i < 7; i++) {
        float rand = rand_0_1();
        if (rand <= numberOfNewsObjects/numeroTotal) {
            numberOfNewsObjects--;
            auto  *box = BGObstacle::create();
            box->getPhysicsBody()->setCategoryBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::Obstacle);
            box->getPhysicsBody()->setContactTestBitmask(true);
            box->setPosition(Vec2((i * (42+3))+4 + 21,(8 * (42+3))+4 + 100 + 21));
            printf("x: %f  y: %f",box->getPosition().x , box->getPosition().y);
            mainLayer->addChild(box, 1);
            arrayOfObstacle.pushBack(box);
            printf(" +%d\n ", i);
        }
}
```

The `BGObstacle` is a subclass of `DrawNode`

use this and solve

```
 cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->performFunctionInCocosThread(‌​[=](){   for (int i =0 ; i < 7; i++) {
            float rand = rand_0_1();
            if (rand <= numberOfNewsObjects/numeroTotal) {
                numberOfNewsObjects--;
                auto  *box = BGObstacle::create();
                box->getPhysicsBody()->setCategoryBitmask((int)PhysicsCategory::Obstacle);
                box->getPhysicsBody()->setContactTestBitmask(true);
                box->setPosition(Vec2((i * (42+3))+4 + 21,(8 * (42+3))+4 + 100 + 21));
                printf("x: %f  y: %f",box->getPosition().x , box->getPosition().y);
                mainLayer->addChild(box, 1);
                arrayOfObstacle.pushBack(box);
                printf(" +%d\n ", i);
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be fine. Do you change their positions outside this function?
I would consider rewriting `BGObstacle::setPosition(float x, float y)`:

```
BGObstacle::setPosition(float x, float y){
    assert(Vec2(x, y).length()>0.001f);
    Sprite::setPosition(x, y);
}
```

The game will be interrupted and you can see the call stack when any BGObstacle is moved to (0, 0).

Comment: I do this and the position always as right but some times the object appears in (0,0) and i never passe position like (0,0).

Comment: That is actually what I need. If some code changes object position to (0, 0) accidentally, you can pause immediately and see what has happened. @Pedro

Comment: I use it and not exist any code do that. the object have the right position even so it appears at (0,0). can be a cocos2d x bug ? or can be for run inside a onContactBegin event?  @Zen

Comment: use this and solve `cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getScheduler()->performFunctionInCocosThread([=](){});`

Comment: ' the object have the right position even so it appears at (0,0) ' ?  How about adding a label as a child of object to monitor the position of object? Set the text of label in the `setPosition(float x, float y)` function, not `setPosition(const Vec2& vec)`. @Pedro